# 'Invalid conversion from some_type** to const some_type**'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors

I've got a function that requires `const some_type**` as an argument (`some_type` is a struct, and the function needs a pointer to an array of this type). I declared a local variable of type `some_type*`, and initialized it. Then I call the function as `f(&some_array)`, and the compiler (gcc) says:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘some_type**’ to ‘const some_type**’
```

What's the problem here? Why can't I convert a variable to const?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See: [Why can't I pass a `char **` to a function which expects a `const char **`?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)  from the comp.lang.c FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify some more context, for instance is the argument passed data into or out of (or both?) the function?

Try making your variable const as well:

```
some_type const *some_array = ....;
```

This reads as "some_array is a pointer to a const some_type". The code can't modify the thing being pointed at. So you have to declare your variable const before passing it to the function.

(Edited...)

Comment: "No" :) ( http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17 )

Comment: Huh. This was marked as the accepted answer even though it doesn't address the question about "why" at all? =(

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options to get around what jamesdlin outlined in his answer.

You could use an intermediate variable.

```
some_type const* const_some_array = some_array;
f(&const_some_array);
```

You could change the parameters of `f`.

```
void f(some_type const* const* some_array);
```